# Saving a result after iteration into a tuple

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I'm writing a program that will scrape data using Selenium, it will retrive data from a real estate website. Data like price, location, land etc. and later I will add everything to a google sheet. I've managed to scrape everything into separate lists.

Now, the issue is, I want to iterate through one of the lists with small town names using fuction (created a class for getting map data) and calculate driving time using google maps, between each town and 2 of the biggest towns in this country (which are Ljubljana and Maribor). And I dont know how to do that in order to save those values in a tuple in a list (first item in a tuple is for Ljubljana and the second is for Maribor) to look something like this: `all_distance_data = [[52min, 34min], [65min, 57min]...]` where each tuple represents a different small town.

This is my code:

```
MAPS = "https://www.google.com/maps/"
CAPITALS = ["Ljubljana", "Maribor"]
SMALL_TOWNS_EXAMPLE = ["Celje", "Kranj", "Bled"]

....
    def get_map_info(self, city):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchboxinput"]').send_keys(city)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchboxinput"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/button/span/img').click()
        sleep(2)
        for capital in CAPITALS:
            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').clear()
            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys(capital)
            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            sleep(3)
            total_time = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="section-directions-trip-0"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]')
```

This is where I'm stuck, I have the data but I dont know how to save it. When I iterate through capitals, first time I will get the data for Ljubljana and the second time for Maribor. I can append them to a list but they will not be in a tuple, but separate values (exp. list[0] and list[1]), and when I start saving data into a sheet I want to call list[0], and it should autopopulate a column with a tuple value exp. 52min, 34min

Comment: Where do you append values to a list here?

Comment: One option is to create a list and `append()` whatever data you want to that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have `city`, `capital` and `total_time` so create a dictionary

```
...

        self.results = dict()
...
    def get_map_info(self, city):
        if city not in self.results:
            self.results[city] = []
        ...
        for capital in CAPITALS:
            ...
            total_time = self.driver.find_element(...)
            self.results[city].append({capital: total_time})
```

Comment: Thanks Diego, this will do it! I tried to iterate a random list of cities and got the answer like this: 
**{'Celje': [{'Ljubljana': '52 min'}, {'Maribor': '41 min'}], 'Bled': [{'Ljubljana': '38 min'}, {'Maribor': '1 hr 51 min'}], 'Kamnica': [{'Ljubljana': '1 hr 27 min'}, {'Maribor': '7 min'}]}**